# run a command conditionally with netcat and grep

Tags: linux, bash, grep, command, netcat

I need netcat to listen on incomming HTTP requests, and depending on the request, I need to run a script.

So far I have this;

```
netcat -lk 12345 | grep "Keep-Alive"
```

So every time netcat recieves a package that contains a "keep-alive", I need to fire a script.

It needs to run in the crontab...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: how often you want to listen the incoming request?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about this?

```
    #!/bin/bash

    netcat -lk -p 12345 | while read line
    do
        match=$(echo $line | grep -c 'Keep-Alive')
        if [ $match -eq 1 ]; then
            echo "Here run whatever you want..."
        fi
    done
```

Replace the "echo" command with the script you want to execute.

Comment: Super!, thats it!, thanks a lot. I need two of these script in the crontab, thats no problem right?

Comment: @Lectere that's totally fine, inside the if block you can add all the commands you need.

Comment: `if [[ $line =~ Keep-Alive ]]; then ... fi` should work just as well

Comment: Also `if echo "$line" | grep -q 'Keep-Alive'; then`

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
#!/bin/bash
netcat -lk -p 12345 | grep 'Keep-Alive' | while read unused; do
    echo "Here run whatever you want..."
done
```

Or

```
#!/bin/bash
netcat -lk -p 12345 | sed -n '/Keep-Alive/s/.*/found/p' | xargs -n 1 -I {} do_something
# replace do_something by your command.
```

Comment: Hmm.. that's what I also prefer. hence added the answer. Else, @wooghie's answer is equally good. :)

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you have on the client side, it might sit there waiting for netcat/the server to respond.

I did a similar thing to the above but used

```
while true do
   netcat -l 1234 < 404file.txt
```

Where `404file.txt` has `HTTP/1.1 404` FILE NOT FOUND

This disconnects the client and since *netcat* has no 'k' it terminates and restarts because of the while true, all ready to receive and send the 404 again.