# Is a conditional response possible with netcat

Tags: bash, netcat

I want to run netcat (`netcat-openbsd 1.105-7ubuntu1`) and simulate a chat sequence. I want the netcat response automatically.

Example of what I want.

```
NETCAT: nc -l 8080

CLIENT: nc localhost 8080

CLIENT: hello

NETCAT: (if statment) 
        if hello
           do hello friend

        if bye
           do bye friend
           send a FIN tcp 

        default
           date()
```

I copied the code of this question (in the asnwer by @wooghie): [run a command conditionally with netcat and grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17990099/run-a-command-conditionally-with-netcat-and-grep) ...but the message wasn't sent to the client. Netcat was on listen mode.

```
#!/bin/bash

netcat -l 8080 | while read line
do
    match=$(echo $line | grep -c 'Hello')
    if [ $match -eq 1 ]; then
        printf "Hello friend\r\n\r\n"
    fi
done
```

Comment: No. You would need to feed both stdin *and* be fed by stdout. Therefore, to employ `netcat -l` is vastly more complicated/fragile than to re-implement whole `netcat -l` in perl or python.

Comment: @kubanczyk - You totally could using named pipes.  Bash's `coproc` makes it easier though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36327396/477563

Comment: Try adding `expect` to the tags and @GlennJackman may share his immense wisdom on such things....

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44900864/netcat-bidirectional-communication/64186214#64186214) will help

Answer (score 0):

I think you want expect(1). Something along the lines of:

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect
spawn nc localhost 8080
expect {
  hello {
     send "hello dude"
  } bye {
     close
  } -re .* {
     send [date]
  }
}
```

Note that expect is really Tcl, which is very powerful in its own right.
Not tested. YMMV.